# .data() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attr

I have a code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script><script>
$(function(){
$(".classy").data("read","hi");//Not working .working is$("div").attr("data-read","hi");

});</script>
<style>
.classy[data-read='hello']{background:#000;}.classy[data-read='hi']{background:#fff;}</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="classy" data-read="hello">a</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What happening is when document is ready then the data-read attribute of .classy changes to hi.And i have a css style design for `.classy[data-read='hi']` but it is not working when i use `.data()` method to manipulate data-read attribute .it works when i use `.attr()` method to manipulate data-read.Why?

Comment: because `.data()` doesn't set an attribute - its used to store information associated with the DOM element

Comment: So,i can't use .data() in this case

Comment: see the updated code ,now what will you recommend

Comment: Your missing my point - i mean change the class to change the CSS properties - dont use `.data()` or `.attr()`

Comment: dude is here any fault with .attr()

Comment: [attr() works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPXSN/) - im saying dont use data() .... better (IMO) is to use a class - ie add a class or change the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood what `data-xxx` is used for. It's used to populate data inside HTML tags that can later be retrieved using jQuery by using `.data()`.

Example:

```
​console.log($('.classy').data('read'));​​​​​​​​​

$(".classy").data("read","hi");

​console.log($('.classy').data('read'));​​​​​​​​​
```

Output:

```
hello
hi
```

When changing that data later on, it won't  change the `data-xxx` attribute(s) of the element anymore; this also makes it a bad candidate for conditional CSS treatment.

You should use `.addClass()`, `.toggleClass()` and `.removeClass()` in combination with CSS class selectors to make it work.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble sure, why not :) added to answer